# Notificator (fire-and-forget) pattern in Spring Integration Java DSL flow

Tags: spring-integration-dsl

I am working for the first time with Spring Integration so I'm learning fast.

I have a working scenario in which I have to activate multiple subflows, but I must not interrupt or make the primary flow conditional to the outcome of the subflows

[image: EIP diagram]

I have made a diagram that barely resembles what I have to do

- The source is a mere gateway object
- I transform some XML and create a DTO
- I filter upon some system conditions (and if filtering fails, yes, the message must be aborted)
- I need to activate the feedback subflow

  - Only some messages are subject to feedback
  - Create a new feedback message
  - Serialize it (there's an XML part)
  - Send to channel "feedbackChannel" which is JMS to AMQP
- The previous flow MUST always continue with the original message from step 3
- Message is serialized
- Message is signed with HMAC
- A new subflow is activated that needs to record the current time for timeout purposes (yes, a subflow is far overkill)

  - Extract relevant information, e.g. message ID
  - Send this information to a message consumer
  - End here, you don't need to reply to anyone
- Main flow resumes with original message from HMAC step
- Send over the "mainChannel" which is JMS to IBM MQ server

I have created flow definitions with Java DSL. Since I can't copy/paste from virtual desktop, I'll write down in a generalized syntax

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainFlow(... autowired handlers...) {
    return IntegrationFlow.from(MessageChannels.direct())
    .log(...)
    .transform(transformer::transform)
    .filter(filter::filter)
    .enrichHeaders(....) //yes, not documented in the diagram 
    .transform(...)
    .gateway(sendFeedback, g->g.requiresReply(false))
    ......
    .channel("mainChannel")
    .get();
}

@Bean
protected IntegrationFlow sendFeedbackFlow(...) {
    return IntegrationFlow.from(MessageChannels.queue())
    .filter(...)
    .handle(...)
    .channel("feedbackChannel")
    .get();
}
```

The `sendFeedback` flow will only forward those messages that match a certain condition, and this is by design. The problem with `.gateway` and `.wireTap` (wiretap sounded great and was my first attemp) is that if the message is filtered out by the sub-flow, then it means that the main flow won't continue. Actually like a subroutine invocation in imperative programming.

What I need instead is one flow to **notify** the other flow **and continue** no matter what.

The only solution I came with is the following, but I hope there is a cleaner DSL

```java
.handle((payload,headers) -> {
    sendFeedbackFlow.getInputChannel().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload).copyHeaders(headers).build();
    return payload; //this is dirty for me!
})
```

I have explicitly told my flow to continue with the original payload, which isn't something that bad tbh. I believe Spring is missing handlers that consume messages with `void` return type.

The question is: whenever I have to **notify** (and forget) a secondary flow or a gateway component, a service, a channel etc, about a message and continue my flow with the previous message, what should be the correct syntax to use?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is

```
.publishSubscribeChannel(publishSubscribeSpec -> publishSubscribeSpec
                    .subscribe(flow -> flow.channel(Objects.requireNonNull(sendFeedbackFlow().getInputChannel())))
                    .subscribe(flow -> flow.channel(Objects.requireNonNull(nextStepInYourMainFlow.getInputChannel()))))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).